# Looking for a free article citation web/graphical viewer and explorer?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, cross-referencing

I am attempting to find a tool which will produce and hopefully populate a graph of a collection of articles based on their citations. For example, I have approximately 200 references in a Mendeley folder. I want to generate a plot that I can explore that presents articles as nodes and citations as edges, and potentially performs some clustering based on keywords within abstracts.

I would assume such a tool exists, though the more I attempt to locate one and think about how it might work I am beginning to believe the task may be too complex to make a useful tool from. Is there such a free tool? Potentially a "cheap" paid for one?